# The geom smooth line isn't showing up on the graph using the following code

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, interactive

```
# Load the necessary package

`library(ggplot2)`

# Create an interactive scatterplot with hover functionality
`interactive_scatterplot <- ggplot(merged_data, aes(x = healthspend, y = seekdoctor, text = paste("Health Spend: ", healthspend, "<br>Seek Doctor: ", seekdoctor))) +
  geom_point(size = 2, color = "#C06C84") +  # Reduce point size and set point color
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "#6C5B7B") +  # Add linear regression line
  labs(title = "Interactive Scatterplot of Health Spend vs. Seek Doctor",  # Set plot title
       x = "National Expenditure on Healthcare per Capita (Health Spend)",
       y = "Proportion of People Seeking Doctor/Nurse First (Seek Doctor)") +
  theme_minimal() +  # Set a minimal theme
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times"),  # Set font to Times
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),  # Center the plot title
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "lavender"))`

# Create an interactive plot using plotly
`interactive_plot <- ggplotly(interactive_scatterplot, tooltip = "text")

# Display the interactive plot
interactive_plot`
```

How do I solve this issue?I'm unable to get the regression line through the graph in the above plot. I've tried my best to do that

Comment: It's not possible to answer this unless we see a reproducible version of your data. My best guess (and it can only _be_ a guess) is that `healthspend` is not a numeric variable, but rather a character or factor variable. You could try adding `aes(group = 1)` inside `geom_smooth`, but the better solution would be to fix your data. Since you didn't include your data in the question, we can't really help you with that.